# Save and load a jagged array

Tags: c#, serialization, jagged-arrays

How can I save a jagged array in C#?

For example:

I have the following jagged array:

```
double[][,] myJaggedArr=new double[2][,];
myJaggedArr[0]=new double[3,3]{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
myJaggedArr[1]=new double[3,3]{{1,1,1},{2,2,2},{3,3,3}};
```

How can I save this jagged array and how can I load it?

**what if I have a two jagged array and I want to save it in one file?**

I think it is better to make a class having these two jagged arrays so I can save an object of the class.

I know that I can save using serializer, but I can not use it for jagged array.
Do you know how can work around this?

(This is an example of using serializer
 http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/GettingStarted
But I do not know how to use it to save two jagged array in one file
and load it.
)

Comment: If you have 2 or more arrays just wrap them in some class or yet another collection and serialize this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two ways to load and save the jagged array.

1) using BinaryFormatter as Simon Chan suggested above. 
Here is an example:

```
 using system.IO;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;


    [System.Serializable]
    class CudaNetwork {
        public CudaResult[] results {get;set;}
    }
    [System.Serializable]
    class CudaResult {
        public double[] threshold {get;set;}
        public double[,] weight { get; set; }

    }
    var myjaggedArr = new double[2][] { new double[3] { 1, 2, 3 }, new double[3] { 6, 7, 8 } };
    var myjaggedArr2 = new double[2][,] { new double[2,3] { {10,10,10}, {20, 30,50} }, new double[2,3] { {60, 70, 80},{40,30,60} } };


    var myclass = new CudaNetwork
                {
            results = new CudaResult[2] 
           };

                myclass.results[0] = new CudaResult() { threshold = myjaggedArr[0],weight=myjaggedArr2[0] };
                myclass.results[1] = new CudaResult() { threshold = myjaggedArr[1],weight=myjaggedArr2[1] };

var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

using (
var file = File.Create("mydata.bin"))
{

    formatter.Serialize(file, myclass);
}
using (
var file = File.OpenRead("mydata.bin"))
{
    var obj = formatter.Deserialize(file);
}
```

---

2) There is another way to do this using ProtoBuf. Here is an example:
(You should add the reference for ProtoBuf at first.)

```
using ProtoBuf;  
using system.IO;

    [ProtoContract]
    class CudaNetwork {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public CudaResult[] results {get;set;}
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    class CudaResult {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public double[] threshold {get;set;}
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public double[] weight { get; set; }

    }



var myjaggedArr = new double[2][] { new double[3] { 1, 2, 3 }, new double[3] { 6, 7, 8 } };
var myjaggedArr2 = new double[2][,] { new double[2,3] { {10,10,10}, {20, 30,50} }, new double[2,3] { {60, 70, 80},{40,30,60} } };

 double[] tmp=new double[myjaggedArr2[0].Length];
 Buffer.BlockCopy(myjaggedArr2[0],0,tmp,0,sizeof(double)*tmp.Length);

 double[] tmp2=new double[myjaggedArr2[1].Length];
 Buffer.BlockCopy(myjaggedArr2[1],0,tmp2,0,sizeof(double)*tmp2.Length);



myclass.results[0] = new CudaResult() { threshold = myjaggedArr[0],weight=tmp };
            myclass.results[1] = new CudaResult() { threshold =myjaggedArr[1] ,weight=tmp2 };

using (var file = File.Create("trainedNetwork.bin")) {
        Serializer.Serialize(file, myclass);
    }


    CudaNetwork cudaclass;
    using (var file =File.OpenRead("trainedNetwork.bin"))
    {

        cudaclass = Serializer.Deserialize<CudaNetwork>(file);
    }
```

Using ProtoBuf, we should have only one-dimentional array; that is why I used Blockcopy in order to convert the two-dimentional array to one dimentional array.

I am sure there are many ways to do this. But I know these two ways so far.

Answer (score 1):

you can use XML Serialization with little different way. see the example.

```
 [XmlIgnore]
    public double[][] MyJaggedArr { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public double[][] MyJaggedArr2 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("myJaggedArr")]
    public List<double> MyJaggedArrList
    {
        get { return MyJaggedArr.SelectMany(T => T).ToList();; }
        set { MyJaggedArrList = MyJaggedArr.SelectMany(T => T).ToList(); }
    }

    [XmlElement("myJaggedArr2")]
    public List<double> MyJaggedArr2List
    {
        get { return MyJaggedArr2.SelectMany(T => T).ToList();; }
        set { MyJaggedArrList = MyJaggedArr2.SelectMany(T => T).ToList(); }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please give me more specific example to show how I can save and load data using XmlElement. Do I need any reference to use XmlElement? What should I add to use it then? So far I found two ways to save jagged array. I will write them as the possible answers but I am not sure how can I use XmlElement to save and load jagged array.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem serialize a jagged array, just using the built-in `BinaryFormatter`.

Code example:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

double[][,] myJaggedArr = new double[2][,];
myJaggedArr[0] = new double[3, 3] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
myJaggedArr[1] = new double[3, 3] { { 1, 1, 1 }, { 2, 2, 2 }, { 3, 3, 3 } };

var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
var stream = new MemoryStream();
formatter.Serialize(stream, myJaggedArr);

stream.Position = 0; // Reset the stream position.
var obj = formatter.Deserialize(stream); // Test deserialization.
```

Then the `obj` will just contains your jagged array, or you can save `stream` to a file and load later, using this following code:

```
formatter.Serialize(File.OpenWrite(@"\file\path\to\save"), myJaggedArr);
```

And load it using:

```
// BinaryFormatter.Deserialize() returns an object, you need to cast it to the correct type.
double[][,] obj2 = (double[][,])new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(File.OpenRead(@"test.bin"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you please tell me how can I load the file and fill it again in a jagged array. I used stream.CopyTo(File.OpenWrite(@"test.bin")); to save to a file with the name of test.bin; it saved with 0KB. I think it is not saved well. Also I do know how to load this data and fill it again in another jagged array (or object).

Comment: @Saeed Did you contain `stream.Position = 0;` before saving your file? Or the stream is saved from its end. Similar to the example code, you can use `double[][,] array = (double[][,])new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(File.OpenRead(@"test.bin"));` to get your array back.

Comment: Thank you Simon. It works fine. The only problem is that if we serilize it and try to deserilize it like this, it gives us "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process". I think this can be solved by using var file = File.OpenRead("test.bin"))
{
    var obj = formatter.Deserialize(file);
}
Thank you for you help.