# C# Save Jagged Arrays to Drive

Tags: c#, arrays, save, store, jagged-arrays

I'm looking for a simple way to store a Jagged Array to the Harddrive to load it at a later point.

I found this post for the problem...
[Save and load a jagged array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598238/save-and-load-a-jagged-array)

...but I have a hard time understanding it and I think there must be an easier way of doing this.

The array I'm trying to save has a size of ~8kb

Any Ideas for a different solution?

Comment: Have you tried JSON serialization?

Comment: I never really used serialization. I know how it works in theory but that's pretty much it. Using JSON serialization seems promising. Any tips where I should start to learn more about it?

Comment: There is Json serialization built-in to .NET (JavascriptSerializer) but in most cases you're better off using Json.Net.  `JsonConvert.Serialize( )` should work on a jagged array.  But if you need efficiency/compactness over readability and interoperability the `MemoryStream` answer may be fine for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MemoryStream:

```
double[][,] myJaggedArr = ...
var data = SerializeToStream(myJaggedArr);
var data2 = DeserializeFromStream(data) as double[][,];

public static MemoryStream SerializeToStream(object o)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(stream, o);
    return stream;
}

public static object DeserializeFromStream(MemoryStream stream)
{
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    object o = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    return o;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect.

Comment: One more question: Is there a reason for using "var" for data and data2 instead of setting them as Type MemoryStream and Double[][]?

Comment: var is more general, and you don't have to explicitly type the exact type.